# Change incorrect python path ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda

Did a messed up Anaconda installation from inside virtualenv and then tried to clean out for an Anaconda install outside of virtualenv. Deleted Anaconda according to instructions which left me with a bad path to python:

```
tom@tom-ubuntu:~$ python
bash: /home/tom/anaconda/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

The Ubuntu 14.04 default Python installation can be reached:

```
tom@tom-ubuntu:~$ which python2.7
/usr/bin/python2.7
```

How can I reassign the python2.7 to default python?

I tried to remove (and unlink)

```
tom@tom-ubuntu:~$ rm /home/tom/anaconda/bin/python
rm: cannot remove ‘/home/tom/anaconda/bin/python’: No such file or directory
```

and setting the new link

```
tom@tom-ubuntu:~$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/python’: File exists
```

stuck - any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your shell caches path lookups, and the expansion from `python` to `/home/tom/anaconda/bin/python` is still cached.

Simply clear `python` from that cache:

```
hash -d python
```

Once cleared, `bash` will scan your `PATH` again to find `/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: You can also run `hash -r`, which clears the entire cache (and is easier to remember).